# How to Parametrized POST Request XML body

Tags: xml, post, postman

Here is my code for Random generating StdNo. It is at my collection Pre-Request level

```
  // random generator function
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(min);
            max = Math.floor(max);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            }
    // generate the random value
    var randomVal = getRandomInt(0,100000000)
    // set the value into the global variable
    postman.setGlobalVariable("randomVal",randomVal)
```

Here is my XML POST body, how can I parameterized the stdID, What is the correct syntax

```
   <Stdudent>
    <stdID>{{randomVal}}</stdID>
    <name>S K Ban</name>
    <age>12</age>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I need to pass the global variable called 'randomVal' to the POST XML Body. How to do it ?

Comment: Just provide the solution, check it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The script would be:

```
var randomVal = _.random(0,100000000);
pm.globals.set("randomVal",randomVal);
```

Don't need to write a custom random function, just use `_.random()` of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#random)

Comment: Ok thanks You. How Can I pass this global variable to the POST request body   (row type-xml)                                                                                                                              <Stdudent>
    <stdID>{{randomVal}}</stdID>
    <name>S K Ban</name>
    <age>12</age>

Comment: You actually did it. {{variable_name}}, that’s it.